# Can a database include both ODbL and CC BY-SA works?

Tags: license-compatibility, derivative-works, cc-by-sa, open-data

The CC BY-SA license is [incompatible](https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Licence/Licence_Compatibility#Specific_incompatible_licences) with the ODbL license.

The confusing thing about ODbL is that it seems to pertain to entire databases, rather than to individual works.

Is it possible then to have a database that contains both ODbL data as well as CC BY-SA data?

If not, do I understand correctly that this can be worked around by having two wholly separate databases, one per license, and simply combining the content from both databases on the front-end? (The [ODbL license](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1-0/) states that "A work that constitutes a Collective Database will not be considered a Derivative Database," so I assume so.)

Comment: No such thing as "a database rather than individual works". A database can be a work. The license only applies to the stuff it comes with, it doesn't apply to bits you add on. Note that the only reason the GPL applies to the bits you add on is because it *says so* - "if you don't apply this license also to the bits you add on, then you don't have permission to use the stuff this license comes with". (That's known as copyleft.) Does the ODbL have a copyleft clause?

Comment: @user253751 The [plain-English summary](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/summary/) identifies ODbL as having a "share-alike" requirement, "If you publicly use any adapted version of this database... you must also offer that adapted database under the ODbL." The licenses draws a distinction between Derivative and Collective databases (per the last quote here); the answer to this question largely hinges on when a database is one or the other.

Comment: so then the question is, is your database an adapted version of the ODbL database, or is it the ODbL database alongside your own database? Just like with software libraries.

Comment: @user253751

It's a bit more complex, as the definition of a "work" is different for CC BY-SA than for ODbL, AFAIK. In my case, a CC BY-SA license would apply to a group of strings describing an item. This would be a single entry in a database. ODbL seems to apply to entire databases, though.

What I'm wondering is if I can take entries from an ODbL database and combine them with CC BY-SA entries inside a single database.

Comment: @TinMan I believe "work" is defined by copyright law, not by the license.

Comment: @user253751 Actually, terms like "derivative work" are generally specifically defined in licenses and vary from license to license.

Comment: ODbL defines "produced work" as "a work (such as an image, audiovisual material, text, or sounds) resulting from using the whole or a Substantial part of the Contents (via a search or other query) from this Database, a Derivative Database, or this Database as part of a Collective Database"

Comment: CC BY-SA defines both the terms "licensed material" and "adapted material" — see https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode

Comment: I think I didn't word my comment on the term "work" correctly. The specific term "work" might be defined by copyright law, but in the context of reusing open content and open-source licenses, it's the definition of terms like "derived work"/"adapted material"/"produced work"/etc. that is relevant to whether and how work can be reused. And that does vary from license to license.

Comment: Have you ever resolved this question?

Comment: @Mitar It seems that indeed you shouldn't combine the two in one database. You could have two wholly separate databases, but you have to evaluate whether that's worth the effort.